# setState array is not accepting the value of another array and giving empty data

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, use-state, react-tsx

i am trying to get the images url from the html file input to send them to the backend and upload to cloudinary but the problem is i am having the imagesArr but when i set the images state it isnt working and giving me an empty array
i also tried another methods that was buggy and the set state gave me undefined until i upload the images multiple times

```
   const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const previewFiles = (files: any, imagesArr: any) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files);
    reader.onloadend = async () => {
      imagesArr.push(reader.result);
    };
  };

  const fileOnChangeHandler = async (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let files = e.currentTarget.files;
    let imagesArr: string[] = [];
    Array.from(files!).forEach((file: any) => {
      previewFiles(file, imagesArr);
    });
    setImages((state: any) => [...state, ...imagesArr]);
    console.log("the images array", imagesArr);
    console.log("the set state array", images);
  };
```

and this is my html input element

```
         <input
            className="form-control"
            type="file"
            multiple
            accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/jfif"
            id="formFile"
            onChange={fileOnChangeHandler}
          />
```

the result after console.log

```
the images array
```

Array []
​
0: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAUAAowDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDFWTcBk9PelEucADpVN5kjHIz/AFqeKYSR7WUKQMA153Sx9GkWkndT8rcjnmtKDUpYYwGGV9QKzBKzRsrj5QKltplkGxmBPQE961hKxnOmpLVG/bXUUwJzhvQ1IXU5OeKw1TZJuUsvHbtVmG5+Y…"
​
1: "data:image/jpeg;base64,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…"
​
2: "data:image/jpeg;base64,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…"
​
length: 3
​
: Array []
CreateEvents.tsx:52

```
the set state array
```

Array []
​
length: 0
​
: Array []
CreateEvents.tsx:53

​the set images is empty but the imagesArr is working fine

how can i set the images useState to the imagesArr without giving me undefined first

Comment: When you call `setImages` the `images` variable does not immediately contain the new state, your component will re-render and on that next render `images` will contain the new state

Comment: even on re rendering the images is not containing the new state its giving me the same empty array

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are logging immediately after the set state. React does not immediately update the value, it happens shortly after. If you put your logging in render instead, you will see the data.

More info: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value

Comment: hello adam thanks for replying that didnt work also the value is never updated even when logging multiple times from different places in the app and the value is never set